# centralized authentication for Linux workstations

Tags: linux, authentication

I'm reconfiguring and updating my old Linux workstations. They have old-fashioned NIS+ centralized authentication system and I really worry about the security of this system. What could be the best alternative for NIS?

Comment: Either LDAP or Kerberos.

Comment: Tanks @IgnacioVazquez-Abrams. But do we have anything else? I couldn't believe there isn't something new and simple. Both of your suggestions are quite heavy for setup.

Comment: Of course. You could have something put identical copies of the user DB on every machine. That might even fit some twisted definition of "centralized".